# LINQ: how to do "flat" collection instead of "nested"

Tags: linq, nested

I have a class:

```
public class CommentDto 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    //....
    public List<AttachmentDto> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get AttachmentDto collection, which includes all Attachments from all Comments

I try to do it:

```
        var attachments = comments.Where(p => p.Attachments.Count > 0).Select(p => p.Attachments).ToList();
```

but it returns a collection with nested collections, but I want to have a one collection, which collects attachments from all comments

How to do it?

Comment: Use `SelectMany(p => p.Attachments)`. Note that the `Where` is unnecessary in that case.

Comment: thank you very much! Please, do it as answer and I will vote it!

Comment: I already closed it as a duplicate question but wanted to give you a specific hint. But glad it worked.